# pydantic schema Optional

Tags: fastapi, typing, pydantic

```
from Typing import Optional
    
class PostCreateSchema(BaseModel):
    
         contact_phone:Optional[constr(strip_whitespace=True, min_length=8,max_length=10)]
```

I specified the variable to be Optional but when I submitted the form without filling in the contact_phone field I am still getting the Error "contact_phone: ensure this value has at least 8 characters"

If I remove 'min-length' constraint, it will work as intended and I can submit with an empty field.

How can I make the field optional but yet have a minimum value if filled?

Comment: `Optional[T]` means exactly `Union[T, None]`. In fact if you print `Union[int, None]` you'll see `Optional[int]`. So you would still need to provide an attribute with `None`. Also see [How to have an “optional” field but if present required to conform to non None value?](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1223)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify a default value:

```py
class PostCreateSchema(BaseModel):
    contact_phone: Optional[constr(strip_whitespace=True, min_length=8,max_length=10)] = None
```